# High order function reference JS

Tags: javascript, function, data-binding

the following code is working but I feel that there is a better way. I'm passing a reference to the high order function's scope.

```
    var p=this;
    this.nodeModal.find(".modal-footer .save").click(function(){
        p.saveAndClose();
    });
```

is there a simpler way to pass a reference for a high order function? Some kind of binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, if you are using ES6, with **arrow function**:

```
this.nodeModal.find(".modal-footer .save").click(() => {
    this.saveAndClose();
});
```

Comment: It work! would you explain a little more about what's happening with the arrow function? Thanks

Comment: Sure, sorry I would have explain more of it if I am not using mobile phone lol. arrow function is a new feature for ES6 and is compatible for modern browser like chrome, but in order to use it in older browser, you need to compile your code into ES5 code with a compiler like Babel. arrow function keep the reference of 'this' inside the function, which you can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: BTW, under the hood, Babel simply did the same thing as you did. You can try to compile your code and look inside of it, so it doesn't seems like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.saveAndClose.bind(this)
```

Comment: I've tryed with bind but it didn't work and it throws the following error: TypeError: this.saveAndClose is undefined. I guess because this function isn't define in the high order function scope.